# Count 2 level follower using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a problem to count 2 level follower using spark. The program is to count all the follower and follower of follower. Here is the example of the data :

```
format : USER \t FOLLOWER \n
P1 P2
P1 P3
P2 P4
P2 P3
P3 P4
```

Ilustration :
[image]

From the picture, P1 have 3 two level follower (P2, P3, P4), P2 have 2 (P4 and P3), P3 have 1 (P4), and P4 have 0 
So the output of the program will be :

```
P1 -> 3
P2 -> 2
P3 -> 1
P4 -> 0
```

I have try to grupby the RDD in pyspark, but have no idea the rest of the solution.

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("word count").getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

twt_txt = sc.textFile("follow.txt")
twt_txt = twt_txt.map(lambda x : kv(x))
twt_groupby = twt_txt.groupByKey().map(lambda x : (x[0], list(x[1])))
twt_groupby.collect()
# result : [('1', ['2', '3']), ('2', ['4', '3']), ('3', ['4'])] this is one level follower
# but the problem is 2 level follower
```

**Note** : the actual dataset is 5 GB.

Answer (score 1):

Self join to get the second follower, and merge it with the first follower, explode the array to get the end follower upto 2 level and count.

```
df = spark.read.csv('test.csv', header=True, sep=' ')
df.show()
+----+--------+
|USER|FOLLOWER|
+----+--------+
|  P1|      P2|
|  P1|      P3|
|  P2|      P4|
|  P2|      P3|
|  P3|      P4|
+----+--------+

df.withColumnRenamed('FOLLOWER', 'TEMP') \
  .join(df.withColumnRenamed('USER', 'TEMP'), ['TEMP'], 'left') \
  .withColumn('FOLLOWERS', f.array('FOLLOWER', 'TEMP')) \
  .select(f.col('USER'), f.explode('FOLLOWERS').alias('FOLLOWER')) \
  .filter('FOLLOWER is not NULL') \
  .groupBy('USER').agg(f.array_distinct(f.collect_list('FOLLOWER')).alias('FOLLOWERS')) \
  .withColumn('SIZE', f.size('FOLLOWERS')) \
  .show(truncate=False)

+----+------------+----+
|USER|FOLLOWERS   |SIZE|
+----+------------+----+
|P2  |[P4, P3]    |2   |
|P3  |[P4]        |1   |
|P1  |[P3, P2, P4]|3   |
+----+------------+----+
```